# Execute function from a webpage that is activated onclick

Tags: c#, html, function, button, call

I have to make a console application in C# which retrieve some data from webpages.

I have downloaded the HTML code from the main page of a website.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode= client.DownloadString(linkToWebpage);
```

I have verified the string and it is good.
After this part, I have searched for a specific line in the html code which contains a button and a link.

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="link" onclick="loadornot()" href="http://aaaaa.com/D?WUrtlC1" target="_blank">Click to read more</a>
```

Now i am trying to download html code from the ancored link (the one from the href), but I am redirected to the main page and I am not sure why. Even if I copy the link from href and paste it into a webbrowser, I am redirected to the main page.

I believe that this happens because the button call a function onclick="loadornot()". That's why it doesn't work the way I have tried? And if yes, how could I call that function from my c# application to continue my app?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
I have found out that I need some cookies, more exactly, sessioncode, to make that link work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run javascript code from web page without browser. So, if you really need to execute that function in downloaded page, use some kind of headless browser, like those: [webkitdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) or [awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)

Comment: But the downloaded html code doesnt contain the code from loadornot function. Will it work? Or, for example, webkitdotnet does all the job I need, including the handling of the webpage?

Comment: In addition, i am making an console app, not a windows form